# How to fit the `main` html elment if `aside` is not present?

Tags: javascript, html, css

### I want this only with **CSS-GRID**

I want to fit the `main` element to full width if `aside` is not present.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

div.root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

main {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <aside> aside </aside>
  <main> main </main>
</div>
```

I've search on the SOF and found the following but It didn't work [STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089175/css-grid-stretch-main-if-sidebar-is-empty)

What I've trid is to give the `grid-template-columns` as `auto auto` and add the width to the `aside` but then `main` doesn't stretch to its full width.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

div.root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

aside {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

main {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <!-- <aside> aside </aside> -->
  <main> main </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `+` selector in CSS, though this only works if your `aside` is on the left.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

div.root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  grid-column-start: span 1;
}

main {
  background-color: burlywood;
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}

aside + main {
  grid-column-start: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <!--<aside> aside </aside>-->
  <main> main </main>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="root">
  <aside> aside </aside>
  <main> main </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex;`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

div.root {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display:flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:200px;
}

main {
  background-color: burlywood;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
<!-- <aside> aside </aside> -->
  <main> main </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the result with `css-grid` only

Comment: why do you only want css grid? flexbox is also really nice